# Multiple citations in apacite with natbibapa option result in appending ",1"

Tags: natbib, apacite

I want to cite as "Simpson and Bouvier (2011, 2014a,b)" or "Simpson and Bouvier (2011, 2014a, 2014b)", but with `apacite` and the `natbibapa` option I am obtaining "Simpson and Bouvier (2011,1,1)". How to change this?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}

Got: Simpson and Bouvier (2011,1,1) using \cite{Simpson2011, Simpson2014, Simpson2014a}\\

Desired: Simpson and Bouvier (2011, 2014a,b) or Simpson and Bouvier (2011, 2014a, 2014b)

\begin{thebibliography}{3}

\bibitem[Simpson and Bouvier, 2011]{Simpson2011}
Simpson, H. and Bouvier, M. (2011).
\newblock Title 2011.
\newblock {\em Journal}, vol(num):pages.

\bibitem[Simpson and Bouvier, 2014a]{Simpson2014}
Simpson, H. and Bouvier, M. (2014a).
\newblock Title 2014a.
\newblock {\em Journal}, vol(num):pages.

\bibitem[Simpson and Bouvier, 2014b]{Simpson2014a}
Simpson, H. and Bouvier, B. (2014b).
\newblock Title 2014b.
\newblock {\em Journal}, vol(num):pages.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The items shown in `thebibliography` do not quite look like the entries generated by `apacite.bst` when you use BibTeX. In particular `apacite` uses a more complex way to generate the extra label/letter. It would be possible to manually recreate that, but I think it is easier to use `apacite` with a `.bst` file and BibTeX as intended (and as shown in Mico's answer).

Comment: That's right, thanks @moewe. Please check my comment below Mico's answer.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I am puzzled by your claim that `\citet` produces a citation call-out of the form "Simpson and Bouvier (2011,1,1)" -- at least if the supposition is that the entries in your `thebibliography` environment were created with the help of the `apacite` package and its eponymous bibliography style, *viz.*, `apacite`.

For sure, if I create a small test bib file with three entries and a test LaTeX  document that employs the `apacite` package and the `apacite` bibliography style, `\citet` generates a call-out that's precisely in one of the two formats you have declared to be acceptable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{Simpson2011, author="H. Simpson and M. Bouvier", year=2011, title="Thoughts {A}",}
@misc{Simpson2014a,author="H. Simpson and M. Bouvier", year=2014, title="Thoughts {B}",}
@misc{Simpson2014b,author="H. Simpson and M. Bouvier", year=2014, title="Thoughts {C}",}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % load 'hyperref' last

\begin{document}
Desired: Simpson and Bouvier (2011, 2014a, 2014b)

\verb+\citet+: \citet{Simpson2011,Simpson2014a, Simpson2014b} 
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The MWE *as posted* in the question indeed produces "Simpson and Bouvier (2011,1,1)" for me, so I think it would be good to reword the second paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the issue came from the fact that I generated the `thebibliography` environment from a bib file and a customized `apalike.bst` style, which I afterwards removed for making the MWE. If you replace `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` by `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` in your example, you will have "Simpson and Bouvier (2011,1,1)" again. Why I was mixing `apalike.bst` and the package `apacite` it's a good question...

Comment: @epsilone - The title of your query contains the word `apacite`, not `apalike`.  The only purposeful reason for having the instruction `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` in one's preamble is to use it together with `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`, to create a formatted bibliography that satisfies the requirements of the 6th edition of the "APA manual". You're just asking for trouble to mix and mis-match `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` with `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`. If you feel that my answer misses the point of your query, please go ahead and edit it to clarify what you actually did.

Comment: @moewe - I've updated the first two paragraphs of my answer to address your comment.